# Installing texlive-fonts-extra messing up i3's font-awesome icons

Tags: apt, fonts, latex, texlive

My setup: Ubuntu 20.04, i3 WM
Font-awesome obtained using: `apt install fonts-font-awesome`.

I ventured towards using latex offline. I currently have `texlive-latex-extra` installed. All good till here.

For additional fonts, I ran `apt install texlive-fonts-extra`. At the next reboot, the i3's font-awesome icons are messed up. I have Timeshift'ed back in time. Any advice in resolving font conflicts would be very useful.

These are a couple of Reddit posts regarding the same problem:

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/crjfgl/font_awesome_problems_after_installing_texlivefull/
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/74l3yr/texlivefull_conflicting_with_my_fontawesome_fonts/

I obtained the `font-awesome` package from aptitude, which seems to be different from how they installed it (i.e., making `~/.fonts`). Any help in explaining how to leverage their solutions would be very useful as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem via the following steps:

- `apt install texlive-fonts-extra`
- Edited the `font pango` line in `~/.config/i3/config`
  from `font pango:System San Francisco Display 9`
  to `font pango:System San Francisco Display, FontAwesome 9`

Note: The font-awesome icons are still rendered incorrectly inside a text editor. But this successfully resolves the problem for i3.